# Linq query to return as a List from a Model

Tags: c#, linq, list

I had been working with so much posting and getting single records for so long now that I'm a bit lost on why my model cannot get easily hydrated from my linq query.

Model:

```
public class v_TRegister_Email
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string LastFirst { get; set; }
    public string FIRST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string INITIALS { get; set; }
    public string LAST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string ALIAS_NAME { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string EMPLOYEE_NUMBER { get; set; }

}
```

Method for retrieving data

```
//List of Model
List<v_TRegister_Email> tRegisterEmails = new List<v_TRegister_Email>();

// trying to make "query" contain the list<T>
var query = (from s in _db.VtRegisterEmails
                         where s.Email.Contains(id)  //  .Where(n => n.Email == id)
                         select new
                         {
                            //  ???  x = s.Email

                         })
                         .ToList();
```

I typically hydrate a single record with a foreach loop

```
foreach (var q in query)
{
    tRegisterEmails.// .Email = q.Email;
}
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I guess that perhaps my data already matches up from the database to the model

```
  var query = (from s in _db.VtRegisterEmails
                         where s.Email.Contains(id)  //  .Where(n => n.Email == id)
                         select s).ToList();
```

HOWEVER , even if that is the case,  wouldn't I sometimes possible want to loop through the query and that possibly map the fields to my liking?

**How do I do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this?

```
var query = (from s in _db.VtRegisterEmails
                     where s.Email.Contains(id)  //  .Where(n => n.Email == id)
                     select s)
                     .ToList();
```

The database context already pulls down your model, so just project it out, as-is.

Comment: Ya, -- so  _db.VtRegisterEmails is already my model  ...  I'm over-thinking , over-working    rushing    Thank you

Comment: LOL - sweet, glad you're back on track!